# What does a ws() block do in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to convert few `Jenkinsfile`s from [Scripted Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) to [Declarative Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline). I have a block like this in a `Jenkinsfile`:

```
ws("/path/to/dir") {
    // do stuff
}
```

I wonder what does it do exactly and what's the proper way to convert it to the Declarative Pipeline syntax.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ws` allocates a new workspace. you would use this to ensure that nothing else interferes with the location on disk where you are running the enclosed steps.

- this is not as heavy-handed as the `node` step, since `node` will also ensure that it gets run with a separate executor.
- this provides more isolation than the `dir` step, since `dir` will not ensure an isolated location on the filesystem the way `ws` will.

you can use it in a declarative pipeline in the same way as scripted:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('hot_stage') {
      steps {
        sh 'pwd'
        ws('/tmp/hey') {
          sh 'pwd'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

produces output:

```
+ pwd
/opt/jenkins/workspace/tool_jenkins2-test_master-R4LIKJR63O6POQ3PHZRAKWWWGZZEQIVXVDTM2ZWZEBAWE3XKO6CQ
[Pipeline] ws
Running in /tmp/hey
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[hey] Running shell script
+ pwd
/tmp/hey
```

references:

- https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-ws-code-allocate-workspace
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#allocating-workspaces

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. With a declarative pipeline I get an exception though: `java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: /path/to/dir`. Any idea why it can occur ?

Comment: lack of permissions will cause that. could that be happening? maybe you're on a different slave than you were on with the scripted pipeline? i just now tested a path where multiple levels of directories needed to be created, and that worked just great for me. can you post the Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Weird. With declarative pipeline the shell commands get executed under a different user, which seems to cause the permissions issue..

Comment: Note: with `ws()`, relative paths are relative to the "slave root".